# Filtering a large dynamic store in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

My redux store looks something like this:

`threads: [ {id: 1, board: 1}, ...],
posts: [ {id: 1, thread: 1}, ...]`

Viewing a board will add 20 threads to the store. And each page of a thread will add 20 posts to the store.

In addition to this there are new posts and threads automatically coming in every second.

The code which renders a board does something like:

`threads.filter(thread => thread.boardId == props.params.boardId)`

So each time you visit a board it will be filtering hundreds of threads. And each thread will be filtering through thousands of posts for each page.

**How quickly is this going to suffer performance issues and how can I best avoid them?**

I looked at [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) but that seems like it would have to recalculate on each view as the filter changes anyway.

Comment: If you haven't actually hit a performance loss, you shouldn't worry about it.

Reselect might be a good choice for your case, cause of its caching ability.

Answer (score 0):

For now, let's assume that you'll leave out [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) until you need it. It is a handy tool when you scale, but it can be rolled out later when required without much hassle.

One rather useful methodology (which was extracted into an equally useful library called [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr)) is the normalization of your array-of-object collections. Considering the state you described in your questions you should *definitely* check out the logic behind it. What this does is provide you with an *alternate structure* for your store collections, that lends itself to *selecting* individual elements, while not impacting the performance of *filtering* significantly.

Jumping right in, your state *could* probably end up looking like:

```
boards: {
    entities: { 
        board0: { id: "board0", threads: [ thread2, thread4, ...], data: ... },
        board1: { id: "board1", threads: [ thread0, thread3, ...], data: ... },
    },
    ids: [ board0, board1, ... ],
},
threads: {
    entities: { 
        thread0: { id: "thread0", posts: [ post0, post4, ... ], data: ... },
        thread1: { id: "thread1", posts: [ post2, post3, ... ], data: ... },
    },
    ids: [ thread0, thread1, ... ],
},
posts: {
    entities: { 
        post0: { id: "post0", data: ... },
        post1: { id: "post1", data: ... },
    },
    ids: [ post0, post1, ... ],
},
```

This works for a bunch of reasons. First of all, incoming posts and threads are added to the state via actions, which means you can easily normalize them *as they come in*. Instead of dropping a full thread object directly into the `threads` array, you add it at `threads.entities.<threadId>` and update the `boards.<currentBoardId>.threads` array with it's ID. Same goes for incoming `post` objects. And just like that, it's normalized.

Now, when it comes to displaying components, each `board` has a very lightweight list called `threads`. Instead of a filter over an array of length `boards * threads` you have a map over an array of thread IDs visible only on this board, and a dictionary lookup which is inherently fast.

Threads for the visible board:

```
const boardThreads = boards.entities[props.params.boardId].threads
    .map(threadId => threads.entities[threadId]
```

Posts for the selected thread:

```
const threadPosts = threads.entities[selectedThreadId].posts
    .map(postId => posts.entities[postId])
```

The extra `ids` field for each collection isn't necessary but I find it useful. For instance, listing all boards:

```
const allBoards = boards.ids.map(id => boards.entities[id])
```

This could, however, just be done using the `Object.keys` functionality instead. Up to the dev.

It should be said that this comes across as more verbose that a simple array filter, and likely requires thought around adding new objects into the state. However, the three examples I provided include *no array filtering* whatsoever and all the arrays used in the store are just arrays of IDs (which are usually very simple strings). Additionally, this ensures that the *data* associated with an entity is only ever stored *in one place* (`collection.entities`), keeping the state lean and consistent even as it grows.